# Passing an initialized object as parameter in Java to reuse it and not allocating new memory, new object is created anyway

Tags: java, android, memory-management, constructor, garbage-collection

I'm trying to pass an already initialized object to one of my methods. The goal is not allocating new memory. This is how I do:

First of all, I allocate just one time the object:

```
private static Quaternion[] m_Temporary_Auxiliar_Quaternion_Array = new Quaternion[3];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Temporary_Auxiliar_Quaternion_Array.length; i ++){
        m_Temporary_Auxiliar_Quaternion_Array[i] = new Quaternion();
    }
}
```

Then, in some part in my code I have:

```
GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(m_Temporary_4x4_Matrix[5],
    input_is_transposed, m_Temporary_Auxiliar_Quaternion_Array[0]);
```

This is how I want to reuse my quaternion, because I call GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix a lot of times, and I don't want to create a new quaternion with each new iteration.

Inside the GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix method this is how I assign the Quaternion:

```
out_quaternion.setValues(qx, qy, qz, qw);
```

And finally this is how I set the values:

```
public void setValues(float x, float y, float z, float w){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.w = w;
}
```

As you can see this is a very easy function and should not do any strange thing. But my problem is that once setValues is called, the constructor of Quaternion is called (I watched this with the Android Studio debugger), so a new reference to a new Quaternion object is created and my out_quaternion/m_Temporary_Auxiliar_Quaternion_Array[0] reference is lost, resulting in not setting values to the correct Quaternion object.

This is the constructor called:

```
public Quaternion(float p_x, float p_y, float p_z, float p_w) {
    this.x = p_x;
    this.y = p_y;
    this.z = p_z;
    this.w = p_w;
}
```

This has not sense. I can't see what I could be doing wrong. Someone can see a bad practise or something wrong here that involves to call the constructor?

Comment: Why is the constructor being called again?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted calls that constructor at all. What calls that constructor?

Comment: Hi @Emd4600, this is what I would like to know. The constructor is called when setValues is called. I don't know the reason

Comment: Hi @Andy Turner. The constructor is called when setValues is called, I can't understand why

Comment: You're confused: `setValues()` *doesn't* call the constructor. Look at the code. --- Best way to find your problem: Debug it. Put a breakpoint in the constructor, and when it breaks, **look at the call stack**.